# React is losing State inside setInterval with useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a setInterval inside a useEffect to trigger a function to execute with a interval of seconds. But, when the callback is executed the value of state is the value of default state, why?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const i = setInterval(testando, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(i);
  }, []);

  const testando = () => {
    console.log(count); --> here value is 0
    setCount((prev) => prev + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1> {count} </h1> --> here value is right
      <button onClick={() => setCount((prev) => prev + 200)}> Teste </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why does `console.log(count);` matter when it's not being used? `prev` will be correct.

Comment: because in my real application i need it

Comment: Sounds like `testando` should be defined in a `useCallback`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const i = setInterval(testando, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(i);
  }, [count]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put `testando` in useEffect dependecies

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const i = setInterval(testando, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(i);
  }, [testando]);
```

Comment: I don't think so. `testado` is a function. It's not state.

Comment: put console there    setCount((prev) => console.log(prev) || prev + 1); Because it's async

Comment: That doesn't resolve my comment. Putting `testando` in the useEffect dependency array doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove dependency array `[]` in `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
    const i = setInterval(testando, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(i);
  });
```

Comment: By doing so, useEffect will be called on any re-render, may not be the desired behaviour